# Power BI Embedded Analytics Client API: "FailedToValidateDataRole" when calling visual.AddDataField()

Tags: powerbi

I am attempting to add data to a blank Visual using Power BI Embedded Analytics Client API. The visual is type "card".

I am calling `visual.AddDataField("Fields", ...)` in my JavaScript code

This produces the following error:

[FailedToValidateErrorRole Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VuSC.png)

Is ***Fields*** the correct first parameter here? This is the name of the field when using PowerBI itself:

[Power BI card example screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcyph.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/get-visual-capabilities

I added the following line to my source code:

```
let capabilties = await this.visual.getCapabilities();
```

Then I was able to see what the data role was that it was expecting which was actually ***Values***

Once I used this it worked.